# How to use gcc inline assembly in icc?

Tags: gcc, g++, icc

I have the following C code with inline assembly in gcc inline assembly style

```
asm goto("1: jmp %l[t_no]\n"
      "2:\n"
      ".section .altinstructions,\"a\"\n"
      " .long 1b - .\n"
      " .long 0\n"
      " .word %P0\n"
      " .byte 2b - 1b\n"
      " .byte 0\n"
      ".previous\n"
      : : "i" (bit) : : t_no);
```

I would like to compile it with icc but there is an error when compiling:

```
error: invalid constant in assembly language instruction  
asm goto("1: jmp %l[t_no]\n"
```

How to solve the problem? Thank you.

Comment: For the jmp problem: If you were compiling with gcc, I would suspect that you didn't have a t_no label defined in your c code.  For icc, perhaps they don't support specifying labels like this.  Have you tried using `jmp %l1`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use the [-fasm-blocks](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/composerxe/en-us/2011Update/cpp/lin/copts/ccpp_options/option_fasm_blocks.htm) command line option.

Comment: I know that, but errors happen. I believe that this is the problem of AT&T style and Intel style.

Answer (score 0):

icc supports both Intel (nasm) and GNU assembler styles.

For Gnu Syntax use the `__asm__` primitive:

```
__asm__ ("
   movq %rsp, %rbpn
");
```

For Intel Syntax use `__asm{}`:

```
__asm{
  mov      rbp, rsp;
}
```

Comment: Is `asm("something")` for Gnu Syntax or Intel Syntax?

Comment: It's GNU syntax afaik. Perhaps you'll have to insert some preprocessor macros that switch between directives depending on the compiler.

Comment: There is an error for `asm goto("1: jmp %l[t_no]\n")`: error: invalid constant in assembly language instruction. Why?

Comment: Can you update the question with some code? It's hard to say otherwise.